# Discontinuous functions and little oh

Tags: algorithms

Does a function have to be continuous for asymptotic bounds to apply 
For example, if we had the following function

$f(x) = 4x + 20$ if $x < 100$ or $x$ even
     $= x ^{3/2}$ else

and $g(x) = x^2$

then, can we say that $f(x) = o( g(x) )$  [little-oh of $g$]

I had assumed that both functions had to be continuous but I was told otherwise and that the above is a case of $f=o(g)$ since the $\lim$ of $f(x)/g(x) = 0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$

Can anyone please clarify?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can say that $f$ is $o(g)$. And you can say that $f$ is $O(x^{3/2})$.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of the functions needs to be continuous, only the limit condition should hold.
Of course in practice and by the intended purpose of $o$, at least $g$ will be a well-behaved smooth function (at least for sufficiently big $x$, cf. mixedmath's example where $g(x)=x^{3/2}$).